# Grid / Checkbox selection doesn't display check box

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I try to use [Grid / Checkbox selection](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/checkbox-selection) in my code but it doesn't work and no checkbox is displayed in datarows of the gridview.

this is my code:

```
$("#personnelGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [],
    pageable: {
        numeric: false,
        previousNext: false,
        messages: {
            display: "تعداد {2} رکورد نمایش داده شده است",
            empty: "اطلاعاتی برای نمایش وجود ندارد"
        }
    },
    change: function (arg) {
        // do something
    },
    columns: [

        {selectable: true, width: "50px"},
        {field: "personnelIOId", title: "", hidden: false},
        {field: "personnelId", title: "", hidden: false},
        {field: "nationalId", title: "کد ملی"},
        {field: "firstName", title: "نام"},
        {field: "lastName", title: "نام خانوادگی"},
        {field: "lastEnterDate", title: "تاریخ ورود"},
        {field: "lastEnterTime", title: "ساعت ورود"},
        {field: "skill", title: "تخصص"},
        {
            field: "",
            title: "جزییات",
            width: 100,
            template: "<img src='/resources/content/icon/info_red.png' class='detailsIconGrid' onclick='displayDetails(#=personnelId#)'/>"
        }
    ],
    dataBound: function (e) {
        $(".checkbox").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(e.target).closest("tr").toggleClass("k-state-selected");
        });

        var rows = e.sender.element.find("tr");
        rows.each(function (e) {
            $(this).children().first().on("click", onFirstTDClick);
        })
    }
});
```

I add somewhere else of my code data to my grid.

Comment: what do you mean by  **I add somewhere else of my code data to my grid.** ?

Comment: I have a function that get data from server and add to grid's datasource and display all rows but select column is empty.

Comment: Could u please provide the version of Kendo library?

Comment: I have faced a weird issue but a simple action solved it. Would you try moving hidden fields (personnelIOId, personnelId) to the end of fields ?!